# Copying Object in Java

Tags: java, object

So I've been tasked to work on an algorithm based on Random Mutation Hill Climbing. I have a method RMHC that takes in an ArrayList of weights and two `int`s, one for number of weights and another for iterations. My instructions tell me to create an initial solution, copy it and then apply a mutation method `SmallChange()` to the initial solution. I was also instructed on how to copy the solution with the `GetSol()` method in my `ScalesSolution` class. The mutation takes in a binary String value (i.e `11101`) and changes a random substring in the binary to either `0` or `1` so I may be met with an output such as `10101` if the 2nd substring is mutated.

My issue is that when I make the `SmallChange()` to my solution, it makes the change to the original solution also.

I've already tried adding a copy constructor as what was suggested in another question I'd found, but it did not work.

#### Main Method

```
public class Worksheet9 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Double> myArray = new ArrayList<Double>();

    myArray.add(1.0);
    myArray.add(2.0);
    myArray.add(3.0);
    myArray.add(4.0);
    myArray.add(10.0);

    RMHC(myArray, 5, 2);
}
```

#### RMHC Method

```
public static ScalesSolution RMHC(ArrayList<Double> weights,int n,int iter)
{

    ScalesSolution oldsol = new ScalesSolution(n);
    ScalesSolution newsol = new ScalesSolution(oldsol.GetSol());
    //Attempting Copy Constructor
    ScalesSolution newsol = new ScalesSolution(oldsol);



    double origfitness = oldsol.ScalesFitness(weights);
    System.out.println("Original Fitness: " + origfitness);
    double origfitness1 = newsol.ScalesFitness(weights);
    System.out.println("Cloned Original Fitness: " + origfitness1);
    newsol.SmallChange();
    double origfitness2 = newsol.ScalesFitness(weights);
    System.out.println("Changed Fitness: " + origfitness2);
    double origfitness3 = oldsol.ScalesFitness(weights);
    System.out.println("Cloned Original Fitness: " + origfitness3);

    return(oldsol);
}



}
```

#### ScalesSolution Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScalesSolution
{
private static String scasol;
//Creates a new scales solution based on a string parameter
//The string parameter is checked to see if it contains all zeros     and ones
//Otherwise the random binary string generator is used (n = length of parameter)
#


  public ScalesSolution(ScalesSolution another) {
    this.scasol = another.scasol; // you can access  
  }




public void SmallChange() {

    int n = scasol.length();
    String s = scasol;



    Random rand = new Random();
    int p = (rand.nextInt(n));

    String x;
    x = scasol.substring(0, p);
    if (scasol.charAt(p) == '0') {
        x += '1';
    } else {
        x += '0';
    }
    x += scasol.substring(p + 1, n);
    scasol = x;

}





public String GetSol()
{
    return(scasol);
}


public ScalesSolution(String s)
{
    boolean ok = true;
    int n = s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        char si = s.charAt(i);
        if (si != '0' && si != '1') ok = false;
    }
    if (ok)
    {
        scasol = s;
    }
    else
    {
        scasol = RandomBinaryString(n);
    }
}
private static String RandomBinaryString(int n)
{
    String s = new String();
    //Code goes here
    //Create a random binary string of just ones and zeros of length n

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int x = CS2004.UI(0, 1);
        if(x == 0){
            s += '0';
        } else if (x == 1) {
            s += '1';
        }
    }
    return(s);
}
public ScalesSolution(int n) 
{
    scasol = RandomBinaryString(n); 
}
//This is the fitness function for the Scales problem
//This function returns -1 if the number of weights is less than
//the size of the current solution
public static double ScalesFitness(ArrayList<Double> weights)
{
    if (scasol.length() > weights.size()) return(-1);
    double lhs = 0.0,rhs = 0.0;
    int n = scasol.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (scasol.charAt(i) == '0') {
            lhs += weights.get(i);
            }
        else {
            rhs += weights.get(i);
        }
    }
    //Code goes here
    //Check each element of scasol for a 0 (lhs) and 1 (rhs) add the weight wi
    //to variables lhs and rhs as appropriate

    return(Math.abs(lhs-rhs));
}
//Display the string without a new line
public void print()
{
    System.out.print(scasol);
}
//Display the string with a new line
public void println()
{
    print();
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

When I call the RMHC function in the main method, I get an output like this:

```
Original Fitness: 16.0

Cloned Original Fitness: 16.0

Changed Fitness: 14.0

Cloned Original Fitness: 14.0
```

The 2nd Cloned Original Fitness should also be value 16.0 in this example. Once I figure out this initial issue, I will implement the code into a for loop to include the iterations. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your copy constructor code attempt? I don't see code like that posted within your question. What specific problems were you having with this copy constructor attempt?

Comment: Also, why is the scasol variable static?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names are written in camelCase.

Comment: Yes I think it's the static variable `scasol` messing you up.  There's only one in your program so you *"can't"* make a copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is where you try to copy your data:

```
ScalesSolution oldsol = new ScalesSolution(n);
ScalesSolution newsol = new ScalesSolution(oldsol.GetSol());
```

This doesn't work because the variable is static:

```
public class ScalesSolution
{
   private static String scasol;
   //...

   public String GetSol()
   {
      return(scasol);
   }
```

Since all you do is assign the value to the static string `scasol`, no actual change or copy is made.